# Parse/Swift : PFQueryTableViewController createdAt object not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform, pfquerytableviewcontrolle

I want to add `UIlable` that represent the time when post created 
I tried 3 different methods without any success

PS: Am using `PFQueryTableViewController`

Update :

```
 var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"
        var useDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate
        cell.dateLabel.text = useDate
```

After above Code I get this error > **can't assign of type NSDate -> string to type String?** the error is points to cell.dateLabel.text = useDate

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject ? ) - > PFTableViewCell ? 
{
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellImg", forIndexPath: indexPath) as!MoreCell

  //Trial 1 
  cell.dateLabel.text = object ? .objectForKey(createdAt)

  //Trial 2
  cell.dateLabel.text = object ? .objectForKey("createdAt") as ? String

  //Trial 3
  cell.dateLabel.text = object ? .createdAt
 //Trial 4
  cell.dateLabel.text = object?.updatedAt >> Error Can't assign value of type NSDate to type string?

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty self explanatory. The `updatedAt` token in Parse is a Date object, while you're trying to assign it to something that holds strings. So you need to change the date into a string before trying to set it for your text label.

EDIT:

You need to use your date formatter like this:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"
let useDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(object["updatedAt"] as! NSDate)
cell.dateLabel.text = useDate
```

Comment: Crash > this line >            `let useDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(object!["updatedAt"] as! NSDate)`  >>fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Xcode force me to add ! after `stringFromDate(object`

Comment: check if exists first, if let date = object["updatedAt "] { ... }

Comment: can you explain how to check if it is there or not ?  `if let date = object["updatedAt "]`